# Perl bitwise operation gives unexpected results

Tags: perl

I'm trying to workout the subnet mask and neighbor IP address. When using an AND to find the network ID i get strange results.

Why is this not true, and how can i make it true?

```
if ( ~252&255 == 3 ) {print "hello\n";}
```

I've also tried but I have the same problem

```
if ( ~252&255 == 0x11 ) {print "hello\n";}
```

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8zTUFDQaPOyNRIzcjUVFPB1lbBWEFTobqgKDOvREEpIzUnJz8mT8m69v9/AA)

Comment: @user202729 are you saying it should work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a precedence issue.

```
~252&255 == 3
```

means

```
(~252) & (255 == 3)
```

but you want

```
((~252) & 255) == 3
```

It's unintuitive for comparison operators (e.g. `==`) to have higher precedence than infix bitwise operators (e.g. `&`), but Perl opted to follow C's precedence rules.

> Operators borrowed from C keep the same precedence relationship with each other, even where C's precedence is slightly screwy. (This makes learning Perl easier for C folks.)

[perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Answer (score 2):

`dsm@local:~$ perl -le 'print (~252&255 == 3);'
0
dsm@local:~$ perl -le 'print ((~252&255) == 3);'
1
dsm@local:~$`

Comment: I see. I will try this.